# Can't interpret a matrix multiplication (that somehow applies to the Cauchy-Riemann equations - that is $u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$)

Tags: complex-analysis

**NOTE: this is self learning**

Let $\mathbb{B}$ denote the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ centred at the origin.

let $f:\mathbb{B}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic

Suppose that $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ is constant on $\mathbb{B}$, write $z=x+jy$ and $f(z)=u(x,y)+jv(x,y)$ then

Show that (the matrix:)

$[u, -v]$

$[v, u]$

multiplied by the column vector $(u_x,u_y)$ = the column vector $(0,0)$.

Then deduce that f is constant on $\mathbb{B}$

**What have I done**

I can prove using the definition of holomorphic that $u_x=v_y$ and $v_x=-u_y$, but I don't know even how to interpret that matrix. Unfortunately I can't progress further until I can understand what that matrix represents, so this is as far as I have gotten.

Comment: @GitGud It's supposed to be $(u_x,u_y)$ yes - two "u"s - fixed

Comment: @GitGud then yes, I've fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

The first row of the matrix yields

$$uu_x - vu_y = uu_x - v(-v_x) = uu_x + vv_x = \frac12(u^2+v^2)_x = 0.$$

The second row yields

$$vu_x + uu_y = vv_y + uu_y = \frac12(u^2v + v^2)_y = 0.$$

Since the determinant of the matrix is $u^2 + v^2$, you can deduce $u_x = u_y = 0$. If $u^2+v^2 = 0$, by the constancy of the modulus, otherwise from the nonsingularity of the matrix.

By the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we also have $v_x = v_y = 0$, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I didn't think it'd actually mean multiplication!